# Accessing specific groups of elements in a register memory in verilog

Tags: verilog

Suppose I've declared a memory space containing 8 words of bit length 8 bits by writing the following code :

```
reg [7:0]mem[0:7]
```

and I want to access elements 3 through 5 of the 3rd word and set them to zero.  What should the syntax for this be like?

`reg[0:7]mem[0:7]`

would this be a valid piece of code?  Or does it have to be like initialization 1?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a fairly modern simulator/synth (post- V2001) then you can directly access part selects in array words:

```
   reg[7:0] mem[0:7];
   initial begin
      mem[3][7:6] = 2'b00;
      mem[3][5:0] = 6'b111111;  // mem[3] = 8'h3f
   end;
```

In older tools, you have to read/write the whole word, and do the bit or part select in a temporary variable.